# Matlab: How do you implement this sum?

Tags: matlab, sum

I need to implement the following:

```
x_i = e ^ (-1 - sum (y_j * A_ji))
```

where `i = 1..10`, `j = 1..5` and `A` is a 5x10 matrix (randomly generated).

I tried using `symsum` but it gave me an index error. Could someone please help me figure out how to implement this?

Comment: Which part of the equation are you having trouble implementing?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I posted the full question I am trying to answer, right now. It is about Wolfe Duals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With

```
A = rand(5,10); %# random 5x10 array
y = rand(1,5);  %# random 1x5 array
```

Your sum becomes

```
x = exp( -1 - y*A);
```

thanks to linear algebra.

Comment: thanks!, that makes sense to me. appreciate it